# Make "Create Team" banner respect sticky setting

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams

I went to the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) page and I noticed that the banner at the top of the page is always sticky, even if you disabled stickiness for the top bar. This looks weird when stickiness is off. I think the banner should use the stickiness setting of the top bar.  See the following animation:

[image: Stack Overflow for Teams banner]

Also, I just wanted to point out that when you are scrolled to the top of the page, the banner covers part of the Stack Overflow link in the left sidebar. I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a temporary promotion that goes away soon. As such I'm going to let the team focus on more pressing issues.